# Noodles gets disappeared after joining the two different nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

We've installed the animation nodes recently in Blender 2.83.2 in Windows 7 platform. We would like to learn the animation nodes. We installed the animation nodes from [here](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/).

When we try to join two nodes it isn't showing the attachment, but showing the preview while making a attachment, and even the change gets updated when a change is made in the node-1, but we couldn't able to see the noodle(i.e., the attachment between the nodes) between the nodes.

But in the [reference](https://youtu.be/4adXZsNRh1w) we would like to learn, it is displaying..
Do we need to make any settings or any thing to be enabled in order to view the noodles appear between the nodes?

Please help..!! Thanks in advance.!!

These are the screen shots below for clear understanding of the problem:

1. Just created two nodes. Screen shot before making any attachments.
   [image: Before making attachment(i.e., Making a noodle)]
2. While making an attachment(Showing the preview..)
   [image: While making attachment]
3. After making the attachment..
   [image: after making the attachment]
4. When made any changes to the values in the node1, the attached node getting affected.
   (But no noodle is being displayed between the two nodes).

[image: while changing the values in node1]

Comment: Thta's a bug, report it please.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz Can you please tell how to report the bug?

Comment: I would guess [here](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a bug in an add-on and should be reported to the author.

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% that is a bug. Here is how to report it:
[image]

In the main menu on the top left click on help, then choose report a bug. It will send you to a page belonging to the developer section of blender.org. You do need a Blender account to file a bug report, but like all the other Blenderstuff: it's free.
Follow the instructions, they are very straight forward. 
And you're done. Congratulations, you helped the Blender community.